# Error: invalid_scope - This app hasn't been verified to access

Tags: google-api, google-people-api

Has anyone experienced this error before? I have been researching, testing, and banging my head to get this error to go away but nothing seems to work.

This is a similar question to the following posts:

[Error: invalid_scope google read contact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44179967/error-invalid-scope-google-read-contact) 
[Google Api:: Error: invalid_scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44111974/google-api-error-invalid-scope) 
[403 error when calling Google People API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38022171/403-error-when-calling-google-people-api)

Unfortunately, these posts never were resolved or aren't helpful.

What is puzzling is, i'm following the examples listed here: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/samples/samples. Along with testing the ONLY the scopes I need here: https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get.

However, I cannot seem to get past the popup screen that states i'm passing an invalid scope.

FYI, I have the API Console setup to use Google People API, Google+, and Google Contacts. I'm using my client id and api key in the "gapi.auth2.init" config call.

Any insight would be super helpful! Thank you for your time and response.

Comment: I'm assuming this has something to do with it now. https://support.google.com/googleapi/answer/7394288

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a scope issue because my web application has not been verified by Google for OAuth.

As a developer you can test the source by entering your test account(s) here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/risky-access-by-unreviewed-apps

To get approval you must submit the form here: https://support.google.com/code/contact/oauth_app_verification

Comment: Thanks for your answer @bbird40. This seems to be a new requirement, I've never had to submit an approval request for OAuth credentials...

Answer (score 1):

after googling some time I've come across this question and the list of scopes of google:

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes

Just in case this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I copied and paste code from google developers example page
[Search list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list)

and that example didn't work for me. I got the same error about invalid scope...

Solution was to change below line:

```
private static final Collection<String> SCOPES = Arrays.asList("YouTubeScopes.https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl YouTubeScopes.https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner");
```

with following line:

```
private static final Collection<String> SCOPES = Arrays.asList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner");
```

Basically I just get rid of "YouTubeScopes" prefix and it has started to work.